# Wordpress is not reacting on Javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, hook

I am working on one site with custom theme and I can not find what is making problems with Java script. Owners of site are not satisfied with idea changing theme or rebranding.

Problem is that in most cases JavaScript is not reacting but it is reloading page.

When I call it in header.php in most of cases it starts to work. But in some cases it is not. 
for example in one plugin there is script:

function freebiesub_form_hooks(){ ?>

```
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery(".freebie-sub-form").submit(function(){var a=jQuery(this),e=a.serialize(),c=a.children("div.replaceArea"),d=c.children("div.replaceArea-error");jQuery(".form-download-button");d.html("");jQuery('input[type="submit"]',a).val("Sending...");jQuery.ajax({type:"POST",url:"<?PHP echo FREEBIESUB_LOCATION; ?>/inc/submit.php",data:e,success:function(b){"true"==b.error?(d.html(b.message),jQuery('input[type="submit"]',a).val("Download")):c.html(b.message)}});return!1});});</script>

<?PHP }
```

and no matter if I will call it again in header or footer or use `add_action( 'wp_footer', 'freebiesub_form_hooks',1 );` in function.php

This theme was not calling `wp_footer` in footer.
My question is what also I need to check in costum theme to solve issues like this.

Comment: can we see the page encountering the problem?

Comment: Yes, please post some more code to give us some more context. One thing to check is if your theme template is calling the wp_footer hook. Additionally, for javascript you want to use `wp_enqueue_script` to load your javascript. There is an option to load in the footer.